# NSButton's @objc action not being triggered in Swift for MacOS app

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton

I have an `NSButton` in my ViewController class that is not triggering its click function (`closeButtonPressed`) when clicked.

I would test with a `Button` but UIKit isn't available for my project, as it's a non-Catalyst app for Mac.

As this has been a challenging and time-consuming issue, I am grateful for your time and expertise in helping me resolve it.

**Minimal reproducible example**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MinimalReproducibleExampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

struct ViewControllerWrapper: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        return ViewController().view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
        // You can add any logic you need here to update the view as needed.
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    let closeButton = NSButton(title: "X", target: nil, action: nil)
    
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.cyan.cgColor
        
        closeButton.target = self
        closeButton.action = #selector(closeButtonPressed)
        closeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 30)
        closeButton.bezelColor = NSColor.gray
        view.addSubview(closeButton)
    }
    
    @objc func closeButtonPressed() {
        print("Close button pressed")
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var viewControllerWrapper: ViewControllerWrapper
    
    init(){
        self.viewControllerWrapper = ViewControllerWrapper()
    }
        var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
                viewControllerWrapper
            }
        }
    }
```

(MacOS 12.6.3, Xcode 14.2)

Comment: You have two different instances of `ViewController` one that you construct in your `AppDelegate`, and one that you construct in your `ViewControllerWrapper`. Is this intentional? Is there a particular reason that you are using `NSViewRepresentable` instead of `NSViewControllerRepresentable`? And where are you registering your `AppDelegate`, I don't see any reference to `NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor`?

Comment: Oh, right. It wasn't intentional and that portion is now removed (although the effect is the same).

Comment: Your code works if you use a `NSViewControllerRepresentable`, but you haven't answered my question as to why you chose to use  `NSViewRepresentable` instead.

Comment: I apologize for that oversight. I'm unusually tired and under the weather. Looking at the rest of your comments/questions.

Comment: The original purpose for the NSViewRepresentable (to wrap the NSViewController) was so that it can be added to other SwiftUI views, rather than displayed as a standalone view. I'm now looking into making the `NSViewControllerRepresentable` work. If that's the solution, thank you, sincerely.

Comment: I'm happy to say that you are correct. `NSViewControllerRepresentable`, used instead of `NSViewRepresentable`, is the solution (Feel free to post as the answer when convenient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using a `NSViewController` you should use `NSViewControllerRepresentable` instead of using `NSViewRepresentable`.

`NSViewControllerRepresentable` is explicitly for use with `NSViewController` while `NSViewRepresentable` is for use with `NView`.

If you can change your `ViewControllerWrapper` to the following:

```
struct ViewControllerWrapper: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        ViewController()
    }

    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

This should allow the button to work.